# Updating Database with sessions not working C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, session-variables, sqlcommand

So my code brings across the searched for userID of a lecturer and the ModuleID previously selected by the user. However it breaks on this line;

```
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error is;

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

I don't know why it does it but I can see that my stuff is being pulled across when I use a break point.

Front end code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Lecturer_Records.UserID, Lecturer_Records.FirstName, Lecturer_Records.Surname, Lecturer_Records.PhoneNumber, Users.Email 
            FROM Lecturer_Records 
            INNER JOIN Users ON Lecturer_Records.UserID = Users.UserID 
            WHERE (Users.Email = @email)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="email" QueryStringField="searchlects" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="ModuleID" SessionField="ModuleID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>




        <asp:GridView ID="SearchResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchResult_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNumber" HeaderText="PhoneNumber" SortExpression="PhoneNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And my C# code

```
    protected void SearchResult_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     // open new connection
        SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        connection1.Open();

        string SearchUser = SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        string Module = (string)Session["ModuleID"];

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Modules] SET (UserID = '" + SearchUser + "') WHERE (ModuleID = '" + Module + "')", connection1);


        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // move on to home page
        Response.Redirect("APMDefault.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any `(` or `)` in your command. They breaks your sql syntax. Just delete them.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Based on your column names, they seems as a numerical types. That means, you might need to delete single quotes as well. If you use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), you will not need this of course.

And use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command.

```
using(var connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
using(var myCommand = connection1.CreateCommand())
{
     myCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE Modules SET UserID = @userid 
                               WHERE ModuleID = @moduleid";
     myCommand.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SearchUser;   
     myCommand.Parameters.Add("@moduleid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Module;
     // I assumed your column types are nvarchar
     connection1.Open();
     myCommand.ExecutenonQuery();
     // move on to home page
     Response.Redirect("APMDefault.aspx");
}
```

But *really*, those columns are seem as numerical types. Either you can their type or change their name that points their types as character.